# Vtiger 6.5 error after installatiion

Tags: crm, vtiger

I've just installed Vtiger 6.5 on windows xampp server, the installation went smoothly but as soon as I started the browser (localhost/vtigercrm) I get this error.

> Fatal error: Cannot unset $this in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\libraries\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php on line 160

Does anyone know what I've done wrong? I've downloaded and tried it several times, I've also changed the php.ini file according to the manual but doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Which version of PHP you are using? I think you have installed PHP 7. If yes then please install xamp with PHP 5.* version

Answer (score 2):

This error may occurs in PHP 7 version. So proposed solution is below.
Please update that function with this one in file `vtigercrm\libraries\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php on line 160`

```
function Destroy() {
    ini_set("magic_quotes_runtime", $this->mgq ); //Add this line
    unset( $this );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to occur when we try to install vTiger6.5 in PHP 7. For me the vTiger6.5 got successfully installed after commenting the line number 160 and 2214.

Comment the Line number 160 and 2214 in the file vtigercrm\libraries\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php.

unset( $this ); /* comment this line no: 160 and 2214 */

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, changing PHP version to 5.6 (or 5.5 or 5.4) will solve your problem. Although Vtiger 6.5 is supposed to be compatible with php 7, in practice it is not.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when vtiger 6.5 is installed on the PHP 7 installation. Comment the unset ($ this); in the function Destroy ()

Line 160 function destroy () { // unset ($ this); }

Line 2216 function destroy () { ini_set ("magic_quotes_runtime", $ this-> mgq); #set_magic_quotes_runtime ($ this-> mgq); //unset ($ this); }

Answer (score 0):

Open `index.php` file in root and add below mentioned code at start of a file

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);
```

Open `/libraries/adodb/adodb-xmlschema.inc.php` file and then

comment line 160

```
function destroy() {
    //ini_set("magic_quotes_runtime", $this->mgq );
    //unset( $this );
}
```

comment line 2214

```
function Destroy() {
    //ini_set("magic_quotes_runtime", $this->mgq );
    #set_magic_quotes_runtime( $this->mgq );
    //unset( $this );
}
```

and then give 755 permission to /test folder

```
sudo chmod -R 755 test/
```